# How to copy an even number of char to a string in C?

Tags: c, string, char

I'm trying to copy a even number of char in another string. It does not work at all. But if I try to copy a odd number of char it works. I try to use a for and the function strncpy and it print the word that I want plus a randome letter.

```
int position=6;
char *stringFirst=malloc(position);

for(int j=0;j<position;j++){
    stringFirst[j]=fileStingToMod[j];
}

printf("%s",stringFirst);
free(stringFirst);
```

This is another code that I try to run:

```
int position=6;
char *stringFirst=malloc(position);

strncpy(stringFirst,fileStingToMod,position);

printf("%s",stringFirst);
free(stringFirst);
```

In both cases, the code gives me the following output:

> cammelÙ

or

> cammel↓

The string, named `fileStringToMod`, is : `"cammelloverde"`.

Comment: If you want to apply string-format operations on that array of characters, then you set the last character to 0 (null character).

Comment: `printf("%s",stringFirst)` is an example of a string-format operation.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I'm really dumb. But I have a question: Why my code worked with odd nomber of character and not with even number of character?

Comment: @LudovicoLatini undefined behavior does not need to provide wrong results. That's the bad thing about it. It has nothing to do with the number being odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the first six characters of `fileStringtoMod` are copied to the memory pointed by `stringFirst`.

Note that a null terminator is missing to determine the end of a string.

The `%s` format specifier is to print strings, which need to be determined by null, but `stringFirst` has no null terminator.

Using `printf("%s",stringFirst);` invokes [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/12139179).

Use

```
stringFirst[position-1] = '\0';
```

before

```
printf("%s",stringFirst);
```

if you only want to print `"camme"`.

---

Alternatively, you could use

```
printf("%.*s", position, stringFirst);
```

as suggested by @IngoLeonhardt the comments or

```
printf("%.6s", stringFirst);
```

even without having a null terminator in the string.

---

If you want to print 6 characters (like "cammel") you need to allocate memory for 7, not 6 characters as you always need a null terminator to representing strings.

Comment: as an addition: `printf("%.*s", position, stringFirst);` would be ok even without `stringFirst` beiing nul-terminated

Comment: You've got a typo now: it's`%.6s`

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Ah, I knew that this is possible but didn't thought about it. Thank you for hinting. ;-)

Comment: It *is* necessary. Without the point, `%6s` will add additional space if the string is shorter but it won't truncate so nul is still needed

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Need to do more investigation about this. I didn't used such string printing very often. Thank you again. Corrected.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica OK. Thank you. I will take more care about the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the contents of FileStingToMod, but I just guess it is a longer string.

The problem is that in C strings are terminated by a '\0' character, which you are not adding to your new string.

```
int position = 6;
char *stringFirst = malloc(position);
for(int j=0; j<position-1; j++) {
    stringFirst[j]=fileStingToMod[j];
}
stringFirst[position-1] = '\0';
printf("%s",stringFirst);
free(stringFirst);
```

Comment: I solved the problem. It works with stringFirst[position] = '\0'; and not with stringFirst[position-1] = '\0';

Comment: @LudovicoLatini If you only use `stringFirst[position]` you again have undefined behavior because `stringFirst[position]` does not exist. Array indices start at `0`; not `1`.

Comment: @SystemCrash Regarding your first sentence: You can find the content at the end of the question post, which also gives explanation for what's going on here.

Comment: I know but I rely on what I see running the program.

Comment: @LudovicoLatini That's the problem. Just because it shows right at one specific execution on your system, it doesn't mean your code is broken. That's what I meant in my comment to your question as well.

Comment: @LudovicoLatini Beside that: Is `stringFirst[position-1] = '\0';` not working?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Nope it does not work, it prints 5 letters of my string if position is 6.

Comment: @LudovicoLatini It's correct that it prints only 5 characters, since you only allocated 6 characters. 1 character is needed for the null terminator, which is not printed.

Comment: So, if you want to display 6 characters, you need to set position=7